# Can't install RadRails on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

Tags: eclipse, aptana, radrails

I am trying to install the RadRails plug-in on a fresh Eclipse Luna instance (4.4.2), using the following update site: 
http://download.aptana.com/tools/radrails/plugin/install/radrails-bundle

But it always fails with the error below:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Aptana RadRails
>   2.0.5.1278709071-79-7D7BFZcLCUQRF2NWAQhRBC1qP (com.aptana.radrails.feature.feature.group
>   2.0.5.1278709071-79-7D7BFZcLCUQRF2NWAQhRBC1qP)   Missing requirement: Aptana Editor Infrastructure 2.0.5.1278523018-8o57z9icbz-hWlJZG
>   (com.aptana.ide.feature.editors.feature.group
>   2.0.5.1278523018-8o57z9icbz-hWlJZG) requires 'org.eclipse.update.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Aptana Web Development Tools 2.0.5.1278614541-7D-7O7iRJci-jVhz-KFyoijH (com.aptana.ide.feature.feature.group
>   2.0.5.1278614541-7D-7O7iRJci-jVhz-KFyoijH)
>       To: com.aptana.ide.feature.editors.feature.group [2.0.5.1278523018-8o57z9icbz-hWlJZG]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Aptana RadRails 2.0.5.1278709071-79-7D7BFZcLCUQRF2NWAQhRBC1qP (com.aptana.radrails.feature.feature.group
>   2.0.5.1278709071-79-7D7BFZcLCUQRF2NWAQhRBC1qP)
>       To: com.aptana.ide.feature.feature.group [2.0.5.1278614541-7D-7O7iRJci-jVhz-KFyoijH]

What should I do to install RadRails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updatesite :

`http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install`

But from the patchnotes, v 3.6.0 is probably compatible with eclipse 4.3 only...

[Aptana releases notes](https://github.com/aptana/studio3/wiki/Release-Notes)